# Turtle beach headset not working what do I do?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones, headset

I have a turtle beach headset. It’s connected via wired dongle found on pc. I tried out Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy Jellyfish) on my pc and installed it. (I also had this problem on Linux mint, Zorin os, and chimera works fine with windows and Mac) it recognized headphones and had them as default. However no sound came out even though it recognized headphone. Funny thing is microphone still works does anyone know what I need to do to solve this?